# Как записать заголовок HTTP REFERER в переменную?

Tags: php, javascript, http

Подскажите как правильно записать информацию о предыдушем сайте где был пользователь который пришел ко мне на страничку. Делаю так не работает сейчас:

```
$getref = urlencode($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
```

затем вывожу:

```
<?php printf($getref );?>
```

но получается пусто.

Comment: А может, заголовок на самом деле пустой?

Comment: Ну и использовать printf *вот так* - ужасная идея и потенциальный удар по безопасности сайта, замените на echo

Comment: HTTP_REFERER серверная переменная и устанавливается из заголовков запроса Referer  в протоколе http если конкретнее если заголовок не передается то и переменная будет пустая. Такое происходит если пользователь перешел с прямого URL или скрыл его сам.
Так же стоит посмотреть настройки nginx или apache что бы они не затирали эти переменные.

Comment: Для чего вы вообще используете `printf`? Конечно будет пусто, если отключено отображение ошибок. Потому что такой вывод выдаст ошибку. Выведите переменную на экран через `echo $getref` или `print_r($getref)`